# `finish` command was not executed when a breakpoint was hit

Tags: debugging, gdb

Here is part of my gdb script

```
    break __libc_malloc if $x0==1234
    command 1
          finish
          printf "malloc() = 0x%x\n\n",$x0
          continue
    end
```

The breakpoint was triggered. But gdb stopped without 'finish' executed.
If the 'finish' command was deleted, the breakpoint was trigger with both 'print' and 'continue' excuted.
So what was wrong?

Comment: This is [documented behavior](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html): It says `Any other commands in the command list, after a command that resumes execution, are ignored`, and `finish` is one of these commands that resume execution.